# SlidingTabLayout compressing tab text

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am using the SlidingTabLayout.java and SlidingTabStrip.java files along with the Toolbar to create swipeable tabs.

I followed a couple different tutorials now and run into the same problem with how my tabs are displaying. I set setDistributeEvenly to true and changed my code to have four strings rather than 3. Now the text in my tabs are compressing rather than setting the width to the largest string value and allowing overflow for the sliding while in portrait mode. In landscape, the problem doesn't exist. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILBaP.png vs https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXMuK.png

If I remove a string, the problem is solved, and if I add another string, overflow is allowed but it no longer sets the width evenly, but it again works fine in landscape.

My theory is that the calculated width for my four tabs, given the text length, is hitting some weird "sweet" spot for my screen size. It's too big to contain itself on one screen, but it's not big enough for it to trigger overflow.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_square);

Toolbar appToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.square_toolbar);   //creates instance of app_toolbar to serve as actionbar
//setting toolbar to actionbar
setSupportActionBar(appToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //do not have app_toolbar Title

// Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
viewPager.setAdapter(new TabFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), TheSquare.this));

//Give slidingTabLayout ViewPager
SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
//Center the tabs in the layout
 slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);



slidingTabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer(){
    @Override
    public int getIndicatorColor(int position){
        return getResources().getColor(R.color.green);
    }
});

slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);

}
```

**TabFragmentPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class TabFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
final int PAGE_COUNT = 4;
private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Featured", "News", "Sports", "Life"};
private Context context;

public TabFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    return tabTitles[position];
}
}
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@color/white"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/square_toolbar"
    layout="@layout/app_toolbar"/>

<com.squareoffs.squareoffs.SlidingTabs.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

I'm a bit out of ideas to test, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not resolve the 'why' of the issue, aside from my theory above, but I added spaces to each string ("News" to "  News  ") so they were equal length and, at least in this particular case, it resolved the problem. It's not an ideal solution as I've had to reduce padding to make sure everything looks similar in the tabs if I want the text to take up equal space but it at least displays properly.